# 400 Bad Request: Failing to Parse Valid XML

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Hello stackoverflow gurus.

I have an XML request with body like this:

```
{<Policy xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CompanyThatWroteBillingSoftware.BusinessObjects"><EffectiveDate>2023-01-25T00:00:00</EffectiveDate><ExpirationDate>2024-01-25T00:00:00</ExpirationDate><PaymentPlanId>2</PaymentPlanId><PolicyId>QC103986</PolicyId><PolicyStatus>Quote</PolicyStatus><SourceSystem>USERNAME</SourceSystem></Policy>}
```

This parses successfully in all online XML parsers I've tried. But when this request hits billing server it throws this exception:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-01-17T15:47:07.4196570Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="18172" ThreadID="94" /><Channel/><Computer>SERVERNAME</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/api-2-133184439071488997</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'Policy' and root namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CompanyThatWroteBillingSoftware.BusinessObjects' (for operation 'ChangePaymentPlan' and contract ('Services',  'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
```

Content type is 'application/xml' and content length is correct.

This same action from the server is functional on other machines with identical code. There must be some kind of data or versioning issue here. Any insight is welcome; I have never used SOAP endpoints before working on this.

Comment: Why do you have it wrapped in `{` and `}`?  With those, it's *not* valid.

Comment: @madreflection I'm not sure where those came from. I copy/pasted this request body directly from inspection of the request in Visual Studio. My string starts with .Append("<Policy...") so I'm not sure how they are being added.

Comment: You copied the debugger's display representation, not the XML itself.

Comment: But now I want to know why you're constructing XML with what looks like a `StringBuilder` (as `.Append(...)` suggests).

Comment: @madreflection That is correct. what should I be using? I inherited this application, and my background is in REST api's with JSON, for which the use of Newtonsoft libraries are standard but I'm not sure what is standard for XML.

Comment: It's a SOAP service, so add a reference to it using "Connected Services".  You'll get all the contract classes you need, which will [de]serialize the XML properly, including the correct namespaces (which is what the message might be suggesting is the problem). Read up on consuming SOAP services in .NET. It's nothing new and there's a lot of information out there.

Comment: The SOAP client that's generated when you add the reference will use the `System.Xml` namespace's classes. That's what there was before JSON.